# Selecting entries from a mysql database where the date formatted in %W format is not equal to a set of days

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table called workshifts and this table has one or many workshift_restdays which is set to days of the week (Monday, Tuesday . . . etc). In a table I call attendances I have a field called attendance_date. I want to get all entries in attendances where the attendance_date, formatted as day of the week(Monday, Tuesday. . . etc), is not equal to the days returned from the workshift's workshift restdays. I tried something like this and it tells me there's an error in my syntax.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(attendance_date,'%W') AS this_date from attendances WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(timelog_date,'%W') NOT IN (Select rest_day FROM work_shift_rest_days WHERE work_shift_id = <workshift_id here>)
```

Anyone come across something like this?

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket at the end and also you have to specify the work_shift_id.

Comment: omg that probably did it. im gonna try it with multiple days. thank you for the reply. i cant believe i missed that one